Unbalanced to balanced conversion for ADC interfacing
I'm currently working on a PCB for an ADC differential interface and the more I read about this the more confused I am. Specifically, I'm confused about the proper termination resistors (if needed) and proper voltage levels. This question is regarding RF signals ranging from 50 MHz to 1 GHz.
Here is an example: 
In this schematic, I want to convert from a single-ended to a differential signal. How should R1 and R2 be chosen, depending on the required voltage amplitude, impedances and balun ratios? In this scenario, assume that the ADC has a high-Z capacitive input impedance (but I will ignore the capacitance for now).
For R1: This will simply be chosen equal to the source impedance, so likely 50 ohm, correct? Then if the balun has a 1:1 ratio, R2 should also be 50 ohm. Furthermore, if the ADC did not only have a capacitive input but a properly terminated impedance, say 50 ohm, resistor R2 would not be needed. Is this so far correct?
With this reasoning, if the balun had an impedance ratio of 4 (secondary / primary), then R2 should be 200 ohm? But what if the ADC again had a input impedance of 100 ohm?
Additionally, for ADC interfacing one cares about the actual voltages. As I understand it, a 1:4 balun should have a voltage ratio of 1:2, but is this true for all baluns?
In this example, if I want to have a 1-V-amplitude differentially on the ADC input, I need to have an amplitude of 500 mV on the balun input?
I find all of this quite confusing, partly because a lot of online resources seem to be not too rigurous on the math. Can anyone recommend a good source

You might start by telling what signals those are (e.g. audio or RF), voltages, impedances, ADC type and purpose of conversion. For all we know, there might be a way to use op-amps instead of transformer, etc.

Sorry, you are right. I've updated the question about frequencies. Regarding ADC type etc. I don't have a specific type in mind. I wonder about these things in a general matter, as I'm not looking for a solution to a specific problem (somewhat maybe), but I want to understand how to arrive at a solution.

You certainly don't want both R1 and R2, just one of them. And if the ADC had a 50-ohm input, you wouldn't need any additional resistors at all, just a 1:1 balun. The balun "transforms" impedances proportionally to the square of its turns ratio. And if you want a voltage ratio of 2, use the 1:4 balun and R2 = 200 ohms.

Is this Ethernet 100 ohm diff/ 50 ohm single ? What is the purpose?  I suggest integrated Mags RJ-45

No, it's not ethernet, it's a differential clock input for a research chip. But yes, 100 ohm diff / 50 ohm single. But as a said, I'm more interested in the general math behind it than actual components or setups.
